# Calling AddHttpClient for named dependency once and getting the httpClient object for every service call from HttpClientFactory is safe or not?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, dotnet-httpclient

In my service, For 3 different external web APIs(which I am going to call), I register three different named httpClient in the ConfigureService method.

I wrote my code in such a way that the below code only executes once in the application lifecycle because it takes a DB call to read other configurations.

```
services.AddHttpClient(name_X,c=>{ c.BaseAddress= "x", ..otherConfigurations})
services.AddHttpClient(name_Y,c=>{ c.BaseAddress= "y", ..otherConfigurations})
services.AddHttpClient(name_Z,c=>{ c.BaseAddress= "z", ..otherConfigurations})
```

But for every service request call, I do `httpClientFactory.CreateClient(name)` to get the client object.
In all the examples on the internet, I see that AddHttpClient happens for every service request but I am only doing it once because to set "otherConfiguration" is a time-consuming call and HttpClientFactory internally returns the same HttpMessageHandler for every call for a given name.

**MyQuestion:**
Is it safe to register the HttpClient named dependency once and Get it in every service call from HttpClientFactory?

Comment: the only problem I can see is the number of instances of `HttpMessageHandler` used at the same time may be tripled (equal to the number of named `HttpClient`). As long as that count is under the current system's limit, it would be fine. At best, always try testing its performance to find out the actual issues you may have.

Comment: I am expecting three HttpMessageHandler as there are three named client, I am just worried if timer expires and HttpMessageHandler get disposed or DefaultHttpClientFactory is not creating new HttpClient object using the configuration which i added once during application startup in AddHttpClient

Comment: I think it's fine, the factory should ensure you a working instance of `HttpClient` with the configurations you set once. Otherwise it would be an error in designing the factory. In this scenario, you're just an user who uses the factory, you don't really need to care about how it's created and if it's working. The created instances should be configured with what you've declared (once).